# Cancelling terms in an infinite series over $\mathbb{N}^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, zeta-functions

I try to understand Don Zagiers [seemingly simple proof](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/ValuesofZetaFunsAndApplications/fulltext.pdf) of the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{0<j<k,\ j\ \text{even}}\zeta(j)\zeta(k-j)=\frac{k+1}{2}\zeta(k)\ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (k\geq4\text{ even})\ .
\end{align*}
I figured out everything but one step:
\begin{align}
  \sum_{m,n>0}f(m,n)-f(m+n,n)-f(m,m+n)=\sum_{n>0}f(n,n)
\end{align}
where (for the case k=4)
\begin{align*}
  f(m,n)=\frac{1}{mn^3}+\frac{1}{2m^2n^2}+\frac{1}{m^3n}\ .
 \end{align*}
If $\ \sum_{m,n>0}f(m,n)\ $ existed, you could split up the sum and you would easily see that the sum over $f(m,n)$ with $m\neq n$ cancels with the sums over $f(m+n,n)$ and $f(m,m+n)$. Zagier illustrates this argument by
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{m,n>0}f(m,n)-f(m+n,n)-f(m,m+n)&=\left(\sum_{m,n>0}-\sum_{m>n>0}-\sum_{n>m>0}\right)f(m,n)\\&=\sum_{n>0}f(n,n)
 \end{align*}
However the sums over the single terms do not exist - due to the divergence of the harmonic series. So what am I missing here?

Comment: I think the way I would do this rigorously here would be to consider the "square" partial sums $\sum_{n \leq N, m \leq N}$, perform the same calculation which is now possible since they're finite sums, and then let $N$ tend to infinity, but there's no way to know whether that's what the author had in mind.